# How to select max date value while selecting max value

Tags: postgresql

I have the following sample from a table with students results with date for a school entry exam
[image]

First student passed exam - This is the most common record found for most students

Second student failed 1st time entry and passed second time based on the date

3rd student had a failed input entry and was corrected based on the Version
[image]

I need the results to like like the picture above, so we take into regard using the latest date and highest version!

My basic query thus far is

```
select studentid 
,examdate --(Date)   
,result -- (charvar)
from StudentEntryExam
```

How should I approach this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=21ccc96a5c8dde3e9de6d0dc60a6749a)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (studentid)
    *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY studentid, examdate DESC, version DESC
```

`DISTINCT ON` returns the first record of an ordered group. In that case the groups are the `studentid`s. You must find the correct order to set the required record first. So, you need to order by `studentid`, of course. Then you need the most recent `examdate` first, which can be achieved with `DESC` order. If there are two records on the same date, you need to order the highest `version` first as well using the `DESC` modifier, too.

Comment: Why should a certain statement get instable when it comes to more data sets? No, the query is quite ok. I guess, the problem the is somewhere around your system. Well, it is quite hard so check what's wrong with it when one cannot see it...